# MgO as food supplement - solubility in water

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, ph, oxides

A number of magnesium food / sports supplements contain it as MgO - which is practically unsoluble in water. The recommended quantity is somewhere around .3g / day, so not an insignificant amount.

How is that supposed to work? Does it rely on the pH shifts in the human gut? I've tried to check MgO solubility in water depending on pH, but the [publication I've found](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1385894708002210) is behind a paywall.

Edit: IvanNeretin has pointed out that MgO will react with stomach acid, not dissolve in it. I suppose that's what the manufacturers go for.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it is magnesium oxide and not *magnesium(II) content* calculated/normalized for MgO?

Comment: @andselisk I'd like to link to some without advertising for them, so here's one that I just googled, no endorsement whatsoever: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81c97Tz0qmL._AC_SL1500_.jpg OR https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81tcFDPbR8L._AC_SL1500_.jpg

Comment: Then again, it might be genuine MgO, because why not. Of course it will dissolve in the stomach.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Can you link to any data about MgO solubility depending on pH? Or otherwise whatever makes you sure about it?

Comment: Any entry-level textbook on chemistry will do. Basic oxides react with acids. MgO is a basic oxide. HCl is an acid. That's it.

Comment: @Zubo Well, it might as well be indeed magnesium oxide then. I was a bit skeptical since I happen to take [Maxler's Magnesium B6](https://maxler.com/catalog/vitamins-minerals/magnesium-b6/), which lists **magnesium lactate dihydrate** as the source of magnesium as well as **magnesium stearate** as a filler component, I presume. Photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlKwH.jpg (please ignore the scraps, I had to rip off the label with translation glued on top).

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yeah, that slipped my mind - I was only looking for solubility. I guess that would still depend whether or not there's actually enough of HCl, but I suppose that's what they were going for.

Comment: Using MgO and relying on gastric juice to do its job is not a reliable strategy. Oftentimes people might suffer from low acidity, and if I were manufacturing food supplements I would not take the risk of getting complaints about digestive problems caused by undissolved magnesia.

Comment: Then again, some people suffer from _high_ acidity, and they may use MgO to lower it.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That's not how pharma works. They want maximum coverage for maximum profit with lowest possible risk of side effects. A soluble *organic* salt is a much cheaper solution (sorry for the tautology) for the business.

Comment: @andselisk If you want Mg inside, yes. If you want to lower acidity, no.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Sure, if you want a short-term laxative with a high chance of developing diarrhea:)

Comment: @andselisk Well, Maalox is a thing.

Comment: @IvanNeretin [Maalox is *not* a thing since 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maalox#Manufacturing_suspension_2012).

Comment: @andselisk In Russia, it still is.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Ah, a good old Russian custom of treating patients with drugs prohibited in the West:)

Comment: @andselisk Yeah... In Soviet Russia, drugs test you.

Comment: I actually tried to find the approximate amount of HCl in a given human stomach, but all I can find is the acidity of gastric juice or its production rate, not actually how many equivalents are available at any time.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the tablet might actually skip the gastric acid (if, say, taken on empty stomach or whatever reason) and find itself in the intestine with high pH - I wonder if there would be any absorption after that.

Answer (score 1):

> MgO will react with stomach acid, not dissolve in it. I suppose that's what the manufacturers go for.

This is not factually right at all. Stating the metal content as an oxide is an century old tradition of quoting the metal content as oxides. Magnesium percentage quoted as percent MgO does not mean that the tablet actually contains magnesium oxide. The links OP provided in the comments shows that the tablet actually contains magnesium stearate. This is done to avoid upsetting the stomach because a very water soluble magnesium salt can induce diarrhea in a few hours.

Magnesium steareate is a salt of a fatty acid, which is rather water insoluble as expected but it has some fat solubility. So when you take it with food which has some fats along with this fatty magnesium salt, there must a be slow absorption of the fatty salt by the body hence the tummy is happy.

Basically, you are eating a magnesium soap!

Comment: The second link shows no stearate (which is precisely why I added it). I agree, there are supplements that basically mix every which salt possible - citrate, maleate, stearate, etc. But some contain only the oxide, hence my question.

Comment: If you can read the first sentence carefully, once again, you will learn that your question negates all the basic principles of chemistry. MgO is a basic oxide, it will dissolve in the stomach acid. It is simple acid-base chemistry.